# How do I modify an ext filesystem item given its inode number?

Tags: inode, ext

How do I modify a file/directory given their inode numbers?

Those inodes do not appear on a mounted filesystem as traversable directories / readable files and as such are undiscoverable by `find` utility. `fsck` is helpless. Even `debugfs` has a hard time dealing with them.

Normally inodes appear similar to this:

```
debugfs:  ncheck 10622537
Inode   Pathname
10622537        /lost+found/#10622537
```

But a <s>divine intervention</s> system fault awarded me with these two:

```
debugfs:  ncheck 10622530 10496145
Inode   Pathname
10622530        .../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../42120/47954
10496145        .../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../42120
```

Most desired is to move (attach) both to `lost+found` to inspect the contents.

Comment: A colleague of mine named this 'ladders to heavens'.

Comment: Note also how parent and child number of double-dots differ by one.